# The backports upgrading changes all my desktop

Tags: xfce, session, ubuntu-studio

I use Ubuntu Studio 18.04.2 LTS (64 bit Linux) in two desktop PCs (both are the same machine: MSI MS-7788, Intel i5 at 3 GHz, 8 GB RAM) and one laptop HP 250 G5 (Intel Pentium at 1.6 GHz, 8 GB RAM).

When I opened the backports (to get some specific upgrading to some Ubuntu Studio software), a days ago, I get a new desktop design (the typical Ubuntu desktop, which is different in comparison with the Ubuntu Studio xfce desktop screen) when I restarted the devices.

With the help from this webpage, I got to back to my old standard Ubuntu Studio (xfce) desktop in one of my desktop PC and in my laptop.

It can be fixed when we see the session starting panel (when the system
asks our user keyword, before the main desktop screen), there is a little gear where we can select which kind of desktop screen we want to use.

But... In one of my desktop PC I cannot to get that session starting panel appears!!! The system starts inmediately with the main user session and, of course, with the "new" desktop screen look (not xfce)!

Just in case... Both desktop PCs are configured to have two possible sessions: Main administrator (my name, with a personal keyword) and Visitor (without a keyword but with very limited privileges).

What is wrong, here?

What I missed in that PC?

How can I fix this?

Comment: I'm guessing the desktop where you can't select (using the gear-type logo) you have auto-login enabled?   If so, logout and switch then.  You should find the next boot will auto-login to XFCE & your desired Ubuntu-Studio interface (*assuming you've selected last-login-session as used, rather than a specific default-de that isn't xfce*).

Answer (score 0):

From what I can ascertain, you may have installed the "ubuntustudio-gnome-branding" package from the installer, which is not intended for users of the default Ubuntu Studio Xfce install. I recommend typing `sudo apt autoremove --purge ubuntustudio-gnome-branding` into a terminal window to get things back to normal.

Comment: That didn't work in the PC I had the problem. I had to use Synaptic Package Manager to manually remove all the gnome desktop related apps and install all the xfce packages. Now, all is works so fine, but... I don't understand why in the other PCs I didn't have this issue. What could be different in this specific PC? ???

Comment: Installing the "ubuntustudio-gnome-branding" package adds the GNOME desktop and the gdm3 display manager since it's all a dependency of "gnome-session" which is a dependency of the branding package. It would have to have been done intentionally or accidentally, there's no other explanation